# Breeze, Wijmo, Angular and JsonResultsAdapter - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angularjs, breeze, wijmo

I have adapted one of the Wijmo Data (with wijgrid) samples (breeze-native.html) to work with Angular. It does just fine.
However, when I try to adapt it to run on my data, I get the dreaded 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error. As my data is not a 'Breeze Standard', I have used the JsonResultsAdapter and my own Metadata to create the entities. This is ok with Angular, but doesn't like wijmo.

The data from the Northwind example looks like this:
[{"Product_ID":1,"Supplier_ID":1,"Category_ID":1,"Product_Name":"Chai","English_Name":"Dharamsala Tea","Quantity_Per_Unit":"10 boxes x 20 bags","Unit_Price":18.0,"Units_In_Stock":39,"Units_On_Order":0,"Reorder_Level":10,"Discontinued":false},{...}]

My data is like this:
[{"ID":"1","idUser":"1","idOrganisation":"2","isActive":"1","idRole":"1","SubOrganisations":"1","strEMail":"bob@gmail.com","strTel":null,"strUsername":"bob","strPassword":"*196BDEDE2AE4F84CA44C47D54D78478C7E2BD7B7","datCreated":null,"datLastModified":null,"idUserLastModified":null,"idUserCreated":null},{...}]

As there's no real difference, the problem must lie in the metadata or the JsonResultsAdapter.

Here the module with the JsonResultsAdapter:

```
angular.module('app_jsonResultsAdapter',['app_metadata'])
/* jsonResultsAdapter: parses data into entities */
.value('bem_jsonResultsAdapter',
    new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({

        name: "seltec",

        extractResults: function(json) {
            return json.results;
        },
        visitNode: function(node, mappingContext, nodeContext) {
            var entityType = "Users";
            var propertyName = nodeContext.propertyName;
            var ignore = propertyName && propertyName.substr(0, 1) === "$";

            return {
                entityType: entityType,
                nodeId: node.$id,
                nodeRefId: node.$ref,
                ignore: ignore
            };
        }

    }));
```

Here's the module with the metadata:

```
angular.module('app_metadata', ['logger'])

    .factory("bem_metadata", function () {

        var bem_Metadata = {
            getUserMetadata: getUserMetadata
        };

        return bem_Metadata;

        function getUserMetadata(){

        var x = {
            "metadataVersion": "1.0.4",
//            "namingConvention": "camelCase",
            "localQueryComparisonOptions": "caseInsensitiveSQL",
            "structuralTypes": [
                {
                    "shortName": "Users",
                    "namespace": "Models.Seltec-T_Users",
                    "autoGeneratedKeyType": "None",
                    "defaultResourceName": "Users",
                    "dataProperties": [

//  `ID` varchar(38) NOT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "ID",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "isPartOfKey": true,
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `idUser` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "idUser",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `idOrganisation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "idOrganisation",
                            "dataType": "Int32",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "int32"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `isActive` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
                        {
                            "name": "isActive",
                            "dataType": "Boolean",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "bool"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `idRole` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
                        {
                            "name": "idRole",
                            "dataType": "Int32",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "int32"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `SubOrganisations` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
                        {
                            "name": "SubOrganisations",
                            "dataType": "Boolean",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "bool"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `strEMail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "strEMail",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `strTel` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "strTel",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `strUsername` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "strUsername",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `strPassword` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "strPassword",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `datCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "datCreated",
                            "dataType": "DateTime",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "date"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `datLastModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "ID",
                            "dataType": "DateTime",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "date"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `idUserLastModified` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "idUserLastModified",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
//  `idUserCreated` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,
                        {
                            "name": "idUserCreated",
                            "dataType": "String",
                            "validators": [
                                {
                                    "name": "string"
                                }
                            ]
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ],
            "resourceEntityTypeMap": {
                "User": "User"
            }
        }

        return x;
        }
    });
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('app',['app_metadata', 'wijmo'])

.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, bem_metadata){

    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

    var j = new breeze.JsonResultsAdapter({

        name: "seltec",

        extractResults: function(json) {
            return json.results;
        },
        visitNode: function(node, mappingContext, nodeContext) {
            var entityType = "Users";
            var propertyName = nodeContext.propertyName;
            var ignore = propertyName && propertyName.substr(0, 1) === "$";

            return {
                entityType: entityType,
                nodeId: node.$id,
                nodeRefId: node.$ref,
                ignore: ignore
            };
        }
    });

    var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: "http://lanet.local/backend/webservice/public/rest/index.php/",
        hasServerMetadata: false,
        jsonResultsAdapter: j
    });

    var ms = new breeze.MetadataStore();
    var x = bem_metadata.getUserMetadata();
    ms.importMetadata (x)

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService,
        metadataStore: ms
    });

    $scope.users = [];

    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("users");

    manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
        $scope.users = data.results;
        $scope.$digest();
    }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });

});
```

All I have in the html is the grid:

```
<wijgrid id="dataGrid" data="{{users}}" allowEditing="true"  allowSorting="true" columnsAutogenerationMode="none"
         style="width: 600px;">
    <columns>
        <column headerText="Username" dataKey="strUsername"></column>
        <column headerText="Email" dataKey="strEMail"></column>
    </columns>
</wijgrid>
```

What I want to know is, why should my Metadata cause such a problem with the wijgrid. It works with data from a Web API so I know it SHOULD work!!

Ta!
Craig

PS: I guess it would help if I added the Northwind example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="wijmo">
<head>
    <title>Data - BreezeJs without BreezeDataView</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Remote shaped data downloaded by BreezeJs shown in a wijgrid"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content="ComponentOne"/>

    <!--jQuery References-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Theme-->
    <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/themes/aristo/jquery-wijmo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!--Wijmo Widgets CSS-->
    <link href="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20131.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!--Wijmo Widgets JavaScript-->
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20131.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20131.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/wijmo/wijmo.data.breeze.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/wijmo.data.breeze.js"></script>

    <!--Breeze.js References -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/q.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/interop/angular.wijmo.3.20131.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table caption {
            font-size: 150%;
        }

        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
    </style>

    <script id="scriptInit" type="text/javascript">
        $.support.cors = true;


        function ViewModel($scope) {

            var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
                serviceName: "http://demo.componentone.com/aspnet/NorthwindAPI/api/read",
                hasServerMetadata: false
            });
            var ms = new breeze.MetadataStore();

            var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
                dataService: dataService,
                metadataStore: ms
            });

            $scope.products = [];

            var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("Product");

            manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
                $scope.products = data.results;
                $scope.$digest();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                        alert(e);
                    });

        }

    </script>

</head>

<body class="demo-single" ng-controller="ViewModel">


<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Data - BreezeJs without BreezeDataView</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="main demo">


        <h1>Products</h1>
        <wijgrid id="dataGrid" data="{{products}}" allowEditing="true" allowSorting="true"
                 columnsAutogenerationMode="none"
                 style="width: 600px;">
            <columns>
                <column headerText="Product Name" dataKey="Product_Name"></column>
                <column headerText="English Name" dataKey="English_Name"></column>
            </columns>
        </wijgrid>


    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a *lot* of code to debug. I would be easier to answer your question if you'd reduce it to the bare minimum where the issue is still reproducible.

Comment: Thanks but this question is a year old now and no longer an issue.